# Select content from a view for further analysis

Tags: views

The platform I use is Drupal 7 with additional module Views. I have created content about Botany in a hierarchical fashion, for which the inbuilt Taxonomy module seems ideal. The leaves of that hierarchy are lists of Fields. Then I created a View displaying that content:
- Magnoliopsida
-- Solanales
--- Solanaceae
---- Atropa belladonna
---- Solanum tuberosum
-- Magnoliales
--- Magnoliaceae
---- Magnolia kobus
--- Myristicaceae
---- Myristica fragrans

Now I would like to enable the user to browse the hierarchy and select individual leaf entries (e.g. Solanum tuberosum and Magnolia kobus) for further analysis. Meaning that they would have to be stored somewhere and ideally this selection can also be modified/added on to. Based on this selection I want to create further Views and Graphs.

Can this be done without coding?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean for further analysis? Do you just want them to link to the relevant taxonomy page? If so, make the view a block, and put it on every taxonomy page.

Comment: Further analysis means that I want to create Views and Graphs based on the selected data, for example showing common properties of the plants. It won't be simply the corresponding page.

Comment: Basically it's a kind of clipboard functionality I'm looking for. Choose some nodes, send them to the "clipboard", do more analyses with them and be able to edit the clipboard content as well. I have also thought about using a shopping cart for that...